# Getting SQL query output "kpceinit:enter" when using SQL plus in Unix script to fire SQL query to Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sqlplus

I am stuck on a random issue where I am getting SQL query output as "kpceinit:enter"

The SQL query can be as simple as "select sysdate from dual" or when I am running any stored procedure.

This error is randomly coming on any random query or stored procedure.

But this is seen only when I am running the query using SQL plus in Unix shell script.

The SQL query and the stored procedure we are running from years using SQL plus in Unix script. That doesn't changed.

However the change was on Oracle server where a patch was deployed on Oracle server which is to remove optimisation on the NO CACHE Sequence. I believe this might be the issue but the DBA in my company states that there is no issues with this patching or on Oracle server.

We stuck on this issue, and I tried finding this over internet and only thing I found is -
Kpce is a module in Oracle Streams Async Queuing (AQ).

Please help me out.
Thanking you all in advance.

Comment: That seems to be something new, report it to oracle

Comment: Thanks @nbk I have created this issue with my Oracle DBA. As an alternative I have created utility in Java which will perform same thing without this error.